# connect object to listViewItem

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, user-interface, controls

I have an overview of some objects, displayed in a listView.
When an object is selected I want to show a form containing more details about the selected item.

```
public lessonForm(lesson foo)
[get and display data]
```

[...]

```
lessonListView.ItemActivate += lessonSelected;

void lessonSelected(object sender, eventArgs e)
{
    lesson ??? = //REQUESTION MAGIC here.
    new lessonForm(???).Show();
}
```

Since ListViewItems are acutally just texts and not programmatically connected to the lesson-object I used to create them, I have not found a proper way to find the respective lesson-object for each listViewItem.
Sure I could do

```
lesson ??? = Program.listOfAllLessons.Find((candidate) => {
    return candidate.plainTextName == selectedItem.Text //abbrev. on purpose
});
```

However I think it is undisputed that that is just horrible code, on more than one level.
Basically:
I would wish for listViewItem to have an

```
obj underlyingObject;
```

field that allows for easy access to the object represented by the listViewItem.
Is there a functionality that allows for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to store the associated object when creating the `ListViewItem`. As Tag is of type `object` you'd need to cast it appropriately when you read from it.

Comment: I looked through the MSDN page on ListViewItem but that I did miss entirely. 100% what I was looking for. Thanks!